# Word for person who always judges their actions positively

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What do we call a person who always tries to judge their own actions in a positive way, or convince themselves that what they do is always right?

Comment: The norm? Average? or if this is despite much evidence to the contrary, sociopathic?

Comment: We call him Happy.

Comment: is that person can be called  `sanctimonious` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Words like *[egotistic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/egotistic)* or *[egotistical](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/egotistical)* ("Believing oneself to be better and more important than others") may apply, as may *[egocentric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egocentrism)* ("regarding oneself and one's own opinions or interests as most important or valid") or *[narcissistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_personality_disorder)* (as used in phrase *narcissistic personality disorder*).  More generally, terms like *realistic* or *unrealistic* may apply, depending on whether subject's opinion is correct or mistaken.  In some cases, one might call the person a *[Pollyanna](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pollyanna)* ("person who is persistently cheerful and optimistic, even when given cause not to be so") or *[Panglossian](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Panglossian)* ("having the view that this is the best of all possible worlds").

Regarding positive or negative connotations of these and other words, among the set of [near-synonyms](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikisaurus%3aarrogant) *aloof, arrogant, blustery, boastful, bombastic, cocky, conceited, egotistical, flaunting, grandiose, haughty, insolent, narcissistic, ostentatious, pompous, pretentious, self-important, supercilious, uppity, vainglorious, vain, big-headed, high-and-mighty, show-offy, snobbish, snotty, snooty, stuck up, nose in the clouds, holier-than-thou*, in my estimation all carry some negative baggage, and those with the least-negative senses include *arrogant, egotistical, flaunting,* and *supercilious*; and of those four, only *egotistical* is adequately close to the meaning requested in question.  Note that *self-righteous* is a rather more negative label than *egotistical*.  *Realistic*, if you can apply that label, is positive or neutral, and *unrealistic* is negative or neutral.

I have said terms *arrogant, egotistical, flaunting,* and *supercilious* are less negative than others, partly as a consequence of how similar terms are used in Aristotle's [Nicomachean Ethics](http://classics.mit.edu/Aristotle/nicomachaen.html), as for example the lengthy discussion of pride in Book IV part 3.  However, the slightly-technical usage there is uncommon, so only a weak basis for comparison.

Comment: but ego is `negative` word. isn't it? I need positive one

Comment: *Ego* as a word isn't negative.  See recent edit.

Comment: @diEcho: As you can see, most of us assumed you were looking for a negative word.  Maybe we misread your intent entirely, assuming you were looking for a word describing someone who _deluded_ themselves into thinking they were in the right.  If you are looking for a word that describes someone whose motives are pure and noble, then I'd start with _altruistic_, and consult a thesaurus.

Comment: Self-righteous, smug, vain (vanity), toxic positive( toxic positivity ), over positive (over positivity), overoptimistic, complacent, self-satisfied, overbearing, arrogance, arrogant superiority

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you're looking for the term ***self-righteous***.  From an on-line dictionary:

> **self-righteous** ▸ adjective: *showing that you are too proud of your own moral behavior or beliefs, especially in a way that annoys
>   other people*

Synonyms include *smug*, *priggish*, and *sanctimonious*.  Sometimes, the idiom *holier-than-thou* is used.

Answer (score 2):

How about ***complacent***. From Oxford Dictionary.

*Complacent:* showing smug or uncritical satisfaction with oneself or one's achievements: *you can't afford to be complacent about security.*

Answer (score 1):

I would rather call such a person a **bigot**: a prejudiced person who is intolerant to opinions other than his own.

Comment: Bigot has a *very* negative connotation, as it implies racial and even religious prejudice.

Answer (score 1):

We normally refer to what such a person does as [self-justification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-justification), and because we normally *don't agree* with his position, we tend to associate the term with *making excuses for wrong behaviour*, rather than *judging oneself positively*.

Nevertheless, I think he can be called a [self-justifier](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/self-justifier) *- one who excuses or justifies himself.*